# Javascript Nested While Loops using Document.Write

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, document.write

I am simply trying to run a javascript that will create a "grid" table for me. Here's my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <style>

        * {margin: 0;}

        body {width: 100%; height: 100%;}

        table {margin: 20px auto; border-collapse: collapse;}

        td {border: thin solid black; height: 5px; width: 5px;}

    </style>    
</head>

<body>      
    <table>     
        <script>

            var x = 1;
            var y = 1;

            while (x < 10) {            
                document.write("<tr>");             
                    while (y < 10) {
                        document.write("<td></td>");
                        y++;
                    }                   
                    document.write("</tr>");                    
                    x++;                
            }           

        </script>       
    </table>        
</body>
```

When I run this, the nested WHILE loop works but the first one only runs once giving me one row of 9 blocks.

However if I comment out the nested loop and add in a simple output to make it look like...

```
<script>

        var x = 1;            

        while (x < 10) {            
            document.write("<tr>");             
            document.write("<td></td>");                     
            document.write("</tr>");                    

            x++;                
        }           

</script>
```

It will correctly print out 1 column of 9 rows... what am I missing??

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to reset your y-var after exiting the y-loop.

Comment: Give this a read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: sounds like you answered your own question. if you want only one column you're missing negative one while loops... that is to say, you have too many while loops......

Comment: also you should aviod using document.write. try innerHTML instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset your y-variable after the y-loop finishes, else it will never enter the loop after the first time if exits the loop.
Though, I would recommend using for loops, since those are more appropriate for your case.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    table {
      margin: 20px auto;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td {
      border: thin solid black;
      height: 5px;
      width: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <script>
      var x = 1;
      var y = 1;

      while (x < 10) {
        document.write("<tr>");
        while (y < 10) {
          document.write("<td></td>");
          y++;
        }
        y = 1;
        document.write("</tr>");
        x++;
      }
    </script>
  </table>
</body>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    table {
      margin: 20px auto;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td {
      border: thin solid black;
      height: 5px;
      width: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <script>
      for (var x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
        document.write("<tr>");
        for (var y = 1; y < 10; y++) {
          document.write("<td></td>");
        }
        document.write("</tr>");
      }
    </script>
  </table>
</body>
```

Also note that every time you use the `document.write` method, the browser will have to reparse your whole DOM, which is not good for performance.

Comment: Of course! Thanks so much! I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept as answer if this solved your problem.